# Save before Ctrl C in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python script that receives stock ticks continuously. I use <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to stop the script when I want.

I wish to store the ticks in a dataframe when I use <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd> and then script should stop.

How can I do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` error, then save the appropriate files and exit. I'd recommend putting a way of exiting different from `ctrl + c`, though.

```
try:
 # code
except KeyboardInterrupt:
 # save and exit gracefully
```